# What are the other classes that extend ContentProvider class in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I was asked by a interviewer if I used ContentProvider that not share data with other apps but only to be used by the app that integrating it & Database/dbHelper class are ContentProvider and extended from ContentProvider, hence the question.

I have searched online and even in the android documents and all the places, I saw that it's usually use for sharing data/file etc with other app not to be used as a Database, for that we have sqlite Database.

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider) there you'll find the "known direct subclasses"

Comment: android has some internal classes that extend `ContentProvider` that are not part of the public API, but I can't relate your question to what the interviewer asked you...